# ios: Payment Integration Suggestion Needed

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal, payment-gateway

I am developing travel app. I just want to implement any ios Mobile payment libraries.
I heard that Apple allows only InApp purchases for the payment. Is there any other third party libraries available for the payment transaction.

I want to give services like payment through Credit Card,Debit Card,NetBanking.
Please suggest me best API to achieve these functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can find PayPal, Stripe, BrainTree (ack. by PayPal). Those are the easier to integrate with your app.
They both have a library that integrates and they are super easy to use. Nothing to do with InApp Purchases.